# R creating vector from numbers that begin with the same string

Tags: r, object, vector, numeric

I have multiple numbers in my environment

e.g.

```
num_1 <- 4
num_2 <- 6
num_3 <- 5
...
num_88 <- 19
```

I want create a vector of all the numbers where the value begins with "num_" without having to write out each number individually, Please let me know how to do that

so it would be

```
vec1
(4,6,5,..,19)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get the object values in a `list` and then `unlist` to create the `vector`

```
unlist(mget(ls(pattern = '^num_\\d+$')))
```

---

Or use `paste` with `mget`

```
unlist(mget(paste0("num_", 1:88)))
```